# How to location data in node express mongo

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following schema to store coordinates:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const LocationSchema = new Schema({
    // Matches

    loc: {
        type:
        {
            type: String
        },
        coordinates: [Number]
    },
    member_id: {
        type: String
    }
});

LocationSchema.index({ loc: '2dsphere' });
mongoose.model('locations', LocationSchema);
```

I have also created a get route to get to the page where I want to show this stored coordinates data. When I hit the route I get the following in the console.log which I am using to debug:

```
{ loc: { coordinates: [ 74.360106, 31.497754 ], type: 'Point' },
  _id: 5b5abd4bdcbd0f4e5c70b799,
  member_id: 'HyQUa4_N7',
  __v: 0 }
```

This looks fine to me since I am getting back the coordinates and the member ID. Following is the code for my get route using which I am passing the data to my express handlebars view:

```
// Manage Location 
router.get('/userlocation/:member_id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {

    Location.findOne({ member_id: req.params.member_id })
        .then(locations => {
            console.log(locations);
            res.render('users/userlocation', { locations: locations });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('could not find user location');
        });


});
```

I am confused about how do I show this data in my HTML/View. Normally I use {{variable name}} to show data which is being passed into the view. what format should I use. I tried using {{locations.coordinates[0]}} but that gives me an error.

Please help. This is the first time I am attempting something like this in Node.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the longitude like this:

```
{{locations.loc.coordinates[0]}}
```

I would suggest you should define schema like this:

location: {type: [Number], index: '2d'}, // [, ]

Comment: Thanks Zeeshan for your response, I tried it but I get the following error:

Error: Parse error on line 22:
...de: {{locations.loc.coordinates[0]}}</p>
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

Comment: Have you tried what it's printing? {{locations.loc.coordinates}}

Comment: Yes I did, it is showing the following error:
Error: Parse error on line 22:
...de: {{locations.loc.coordinates[0]}}</p>
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

Comment: Do it like this:

`router.get('/userlocation/:member_id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {

    Location.findOne({ member_id: req.params.member_id })
        .then(locations => {
            console.log(locations);
            res.render('users/userlocation', { locations: typeof locations.loc.coordinates!="undefined"?locations.loc.coordinates:[73,53]});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('could not find user location');
        });
});`

and in view file you can access it like this {{locations[0]}}

Comment: Just for my clarity, if I am passing coordinates in the rote won't they be hardcoded?

Comment: [73,53] this is the default value in case the coordinates are undefined. If coordinates are defined it will pick the original value.

Comment: Still getting error:
Error: Parse error on line 22:
...    <p>Longitude: {{locations[0]}}</p>

Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'

Do I need to change the Schema as well???

Comment: Which template engine are you using? ejs, hbs ? Try to console.log(locations[0]); in route before rendering a view and see what it prints.

Comment: Paste line 22 content here.

Comment: I am using express. Interestingly, I used {{locations}} without making any changes to your code and it is showing me my coordinates from the db.

Comment: When I console.log(locations[0]) it shows me undefined.

Comment: Copy this code.

`router.get('/userlocation/:member_id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => { Location.findOne({ member_id: req.params.member_id }) .then(locations => { console.log(locations); 
var result=locations.loc.coordinates;
console.log(result);

res.render('users/userlocation', { locations: typeof locations.loc.coordinates!="undefined"?locations.loc.coordinates:[73,53]}); }) .catch(error => { console.log('could not find user location'); }); });`

Comment: I see the console log :
{ loc: { coordinates: [ 74.360106, 31.497754 ], type: 'Point' },
  _id: 5b5abd4bdcbd0f4e5c70b799,
  member_id: 'HyQUa4_N7',
  __v: 0 }

Comment: I can also see full coordinates in the browser, both lat and log, but I can't get them separately.
I am using 2dsphere since I will need to find the closest members in my database. Can that be the reason for this problem?

Comment: Can we chat? Would appreciate it a lot

Comment: Modify your scheme like this location: {type: [Number], index: '2d'}, // [, ]